# In PHP: are single quotes safer than double quotes?

Tags: php, security, reference, magento2

I am working on a textarea block on a PHTML page in Magento 2.

In order to generate line breaks using \r and \r\n in the predefined content of the block, I need double quotes instead of single quotes.

Taking into account that PHP interpretes variables in a string with double quotes: 
Is there any possible safety issue when using double quotes instead of single quotes in a textarea in PHP?

If there is a risk: what is the best/easiest way to sanitize the user input in the textblock when making use of double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are dynamically generating PHP from user input and then evaluating it, there is no risk from user input just because you use a double-quoted string literal.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the textarea in a custom contact form in Magento 2. Would you consider that dynamically generating PHP from user input and then evaluating it?

Comment: I agree that I should not have used the term "consider" as it refers to an opinion. Still, I am not sure about the user input risk using double quotes. That is why I am seeking advice from somebody who knows..